# Objective function Convex proof

Tags: linear-programming

This is a question from the textbook that I can trying to figure out.

Show that the objective function $$z = c^{T}x  $$ of a linear programming problem is a convex function

I know that $$z = c_{1}x_{1} + .... + c_{n}x_{n}$$ is definition of objective function.

And function f is convex for all $$x, y \in R^{n}$$ $$\lambda \in [0,1]$$ we have $$f (\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y) \leq \lambda f( x) + (1 - \lambda) f(y) $$

So how do I start this proof...

Comment: By $=>$ do you mean greater than or equal to ($\geq$)?  If so, don't you have the definition of convex backwards?

Comment: Yes sorry that was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Show that the objective function is linear (a stronger condition than convexity). Can you see how convexity follows?

Comment: Could you please name the theorem/lemma that  if a function is linear then it's a convex function?